# How can I force an image link bind by JavaScript to download instead of opening in the same tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, jquery-events

I use this to bind a `href` to a click event on a `li` element:

```
  $(".attachment_file", "#ADlist").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            document.location.href = "upload/Attachments/T" + urlParam('recsel') + "/" +$(this).attr("filename");
        });
    });
```

The problem is that when a filename is a image it opens that image.

How can I force it downloading it instead of opening it?

Comment: Use HTML5 `download` attribute on the actual link? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a. Not sure if you can force download with JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found any way to change the `content-type` from JavaScript it might be impossible (see: [how to set content-disposition = attachment via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3975648/1577343)) so the only thing that remains is to be changed from `.htaccess`.

I could still do it in javascript by changing a `div` inside the `li` into an `a` anchor with JQuery [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) and add the `download` and `href` attribute to that, but I opted for the much simpler and images will just be opened in a new tab:

```
$(".attachment_file", "#ADlist").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
    url = "upload/TravelRequestAttachments/T" + urlParam('recsel') + "/" + $(this).attr("filename");
    window.open(url, '_blank');

    });
});
```