# How to use a button to prompt a download of a PDF?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using a button to prompt the download of a .doc file by doing this :

```
<button type="btn02" class="btn02 btn-default centered" onclick="location.href='http://www.website.com/document/registration_form.docx'">Download Now!</button></h4>
```

CSS

```
.btn02 {
background-color: #FFF;
outline-color: #000;
display: inline-block;
margin-left:20px;
}
```

When I replace the .doc *file on the server* with a PDF (and adjust the code href to reflect that :

`onclick="location.href='http://www.website.com/document/registration_form.pdf'"`)

... It only opens the PDF in the browser Window instead of prompting it to be downloaded by the viewer... Why does the document format change this?

Is there a way I can make the browser prompt a download for the PDF?

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/28946907/7141562

Comment: @AndresMartínez I appreciate that link, that's a lot more Javascript than I'm used to, I was hoping there would be a more inline sort of solution... Adding 'download' doesn't seem to do anything inline.

Answer (score -1):

you can use it

```
<a class="btn02 btn-default centered" onclick="='http://www.website.com/document/registration_form.docx'">Download Now!</a>
```

Comment: Thank you @motjaba this did not work. It broke the button form and would not prompt a download.. I've since clarified my question and added the CSS. Thank you for the help!