# Is there a way to force inline rendering of a file in Jekyll?

Tags: http, markdown, jekyll, content-disposition

I have a blog in Jekyll and on one of the pages I have two links: one is to a `.tex` file and the other is to a `.pdf` file. When the link to the PDF file is clicked, the browser displays the PDF, no problem. However, when the link to the TeX file is clicked, the browser downloads the TeX file.

Is there a way to get the browser to display the TeX file as just plain text? This is the behaviour on some other websites. I know this is related to the `Content-Disposition` response in HTTP but how to I set this in a regular Jekyll Markdown file?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This is handled by the default applications in the user's browser. As far as I know, there is nothing you can do to control this.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975648/how-to-set-content-disposition-attachment-via-javascript