# AngularJS How to download txt,png files instead of previewing it in new tab using window.open

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get my file url form backend api, now I want to download it when user click the button.

It works when the file is excel(`xlsx`）, but for `txt` files or pictures(`jpeg`，`png`), it will only open in a new tab instead of downloading it.

```
$scope.download = function (row) {
        var url = row.entity.downloadUrl;//the correct path of file server
        window.open(url, "_blank");//problem lies in here
};
```

How to make it in AngularJS?

Below is the request

[image]

Comment: Hope this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54723810/90172 could help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
 document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
 downloadLink.style = "display: none";
 downloadLink.href = value.FilePath;
 downloadLink.download = value.FileName;
 downloadLink.click();
 downloadLink.remove();
```